# VBA webpage scrape cannot fill search box, potential security issue..?

Tags: vba, html-parsing, html, scrape, getelementsbyclassname

I have the following abridged code to navigate to a webpage and fill a search box.  However, I cannot understand how to fill the search box, given the classname is embedded in an input element.  Please let me know if you have any insight.  Thanks.

```
Dim ie, results As Object
Dim pagenumber, pagetotal, r, s As Long
Dim finrawebpage As HTMLDocument
Dim searchterm As HTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Integer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
brokersearch = InputBox("ENTER BROKER NAME OR CRD#")
'firmsearch = InputBox("ENTER FIRM NAME OR CRD#")
'geosearch = InputBox("ENTER CITY, STATE, OR ZIP")

Application.StatusBar = "LOADING FINRA SEARCH"

With ie
.Visible = True
.navigate "https://brokercheck.finra.org/"

Do While .busy Or _
.readystate <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set finrawebpage = ie.document

'Set searchterm = finrawebpage.getElementsByTagName("input")
'i = 0
'While i < searchterm.Length
'If searchterm(i).Type = "text" Then
'searchterm(i).Value = brokersearch

'Set searchterm = finrawebpage.getElementsByClassName("ng-pristine ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched")
'If searchterm.Length > 0 Then
'searchterm(0).Value = brokersearch
'End If

finrawebpage.getElementsByClassName("ng-pristine ng-scope ng-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched").Item.Value = brokersearch
'finrawebpage.getElementsByClassName("searchAutoContainer flex-auto").Item.innertext = brokersearch
'finrawebpage.getElementsByClassName("md-raised md-primary md-hue-2 md-button md-ink-ripple").Item.Click

'Wend

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were on the right track based on the commented lines in your code. Try:

```
Do While i < ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input").length
  If ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(i).getAttribute("placeholder") = "Name or CRD#" Then
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(i).value = brokersearch
  End If
Loop
```

This will eliminate the need to hard code the position of the element which has a good chance of breaking if they update the page frequently. That isn't to say keying off the placeholder is perfect, but your options are limited based on what I saw on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I left my computer running the code, and it was stuck on the loop for 14 hours..what do you think is causing the performance issue?